# Changing the journal name for price/discount agreement journals via code

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have found code here: http://dynamics-ax.blogspot.ca/2011/12/ax-2012-using-pricepricediscjournalserv.html
that creates the journals in x++. 
Problem is, i have an external application that passes the information into ax via aif service and determines whether it is a price or sales journal.  So from code i need to change the journal name based on if price/sales, but having problems trying to locate where i can ovverride in it in the code.  I know the link says you can set up the default journal name in procurement and sourcing parameters but again i need to change it via code.  Any ideas?

Comment: In the title of the question you are talking about price and discount journals, but in the text you talk about price and sales journals. Could you clear this up? Also try to take a look at the cross references for the parameter that determines the journal name, that should give you an idea where you would have to place your code to dynamically set the journal name.

Comment: the type of journal is price/discount agreement journals.  then the two types are purchase trade agreement journal and sales trade agreement journal for the journal names

Comment: Did you used standard or custom AIF service?